# Integration of Jquery mobile with phonegap to access camera

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile

I am trying to integrate HTML5 Jquery mobile application with Phonegap to access camera for scanning of barcode but I did not find any example to access camera with phonegap.

I tried an example on "http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_camera_camera.md.html" but it gives navigator.camera is undefined.

Comment: What platform are you on? Did you wait for deviceready event?

Answer (score 0):

In your HTML file put this:

```
<a href="#" onClick="captureImage();" data-role="button">Take a picture</a>
```

And in your JS put this:

```
function captureImage(){
    //SET LIMIT TO THE NUMBER OF PICTURES YOU WANT TO CAPTURE AT ONCE
    navigator.device.capture.captureImage(captureImageSuccess, captureError, {limit: 1});    
}

//ON CAPTURE SUCCESS
function captureImageSuccess(mediaFiles) {  
    var i, len;
    var formatSuccess = function (mediaFile) {
        //DO SOMETHING ON SUCCESS
    };

    //IF YOU ARE CAPTURING MULTIPLE FILES
    for (i = 0, len = mediaFiles.length; i < len; i += 1) {
        mediaFiles[i].getFormatData(formatSuccess, formatError);
        console.log("path: " + mediaFiles[i].fullPath);
        console.log("path: " + mediaFiles[i].name);

        //DO SOMETHING WITH THE CAPTURED FILES

    } 
    console.log("captureImageSuccess");
}

//error functions
function captureError(error) {
    var msg = 'An error occurred during capture: ' + error.code;
    navigator.notification.alert(msg, null, '');
}
function formatError(error) {
    alert("Error getting file format data: " + error.code); 
}
```